# Slow OSClass based website issue since osclass.org is down?

Tags: osclass

I am using Osclass open source script for my classified ads website.

Since OSClass.org is down and OSClass market is closed my website site oc-admin speed is very slow, sometime oc-admin takes more than 40 seconds to login. Similarly oc-admin dashboard loads very slow.

What are causes of these issues and what should I do to get rid of these?

Github url is
https://github.com/osclass/Osclass

For security concerns I cannot put url of my website here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link solve your problem.
https://www.valueweb.gr/forums/osclass/for-osclass-3-8-remove-all-your-website-dependencies-from-osclass-org/

> Blockquote
>   Stripped/nulled all Market connections and admin dashboard visuals from Osclass 3.8.

Here are the changed files only to remove Market connections. The structure is kept for your convenience. You just upload the two folders to replace 12 files.

If you prefer to do it manually here is the documentation:

https://docs.osclasscommunity.com/removing-market/introduction

Attachment: Osclass_380_Stripped_from_Market.zip

Comment: I am unable to register on valueweb.gr to download this file. I have not received verification email when registering.